# Javascript OOP - Why do these two almost exact same statements give different outputs?

Tags: javascript, oop, scope, referenceerror

So I'm new to 'proper' Javascript programming as a whole. I've only ever really used it for simple DOM manipulations with a bit of dabbling in jQuery. Now I'm trying to learn the full concepts of programming in Javascript including OOP and the like. I liked to think I understood a fair bit about scope in JS, but I can't understand this:

```
function Person(name, age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;

    this.getName = function(){
        return name;
    }

    this.setName = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    this.getAge = function(){
        return age;
    }

    this.setAge = function(age){
        this.age = age;
    }
}

p = new Person("Bob", 12);
console.log(p.getName());
console.log(p.getAge());

console.log(name);  //logs "an empty string" - What?
console.log(age);   //logs "ReferenceError: age is not defined" - Expected
```

After the first two `console.log`s came out fine, I wanted to check the values of the properties within the `Person` function to make sure nothing had fallen out of scope. `name` had to some extent (only gave an empty value - but still existed), but age hadn't.

I can't see any typos, which is the only thing I would've understood causing this issue. So why does `console.log(name);` not give a `ReferenceError`?

As much as I'd like to just know the answer, I'd really appreciate a full explanation of the root issue, including any key terminology such as prototypes, lexical scope, hoisting etc.

Comment: `name` is global and a property of `window`.

Comment: Ha! I figured it might be something like that but didn't know. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` identifier exists in browsers' global scope, it's a property of the `window`.

See [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name).

Comment: Thank you too! It makes me curious as to why `window` variables are made completely global instead of only being able to access it through `window.name`. I'd understand if there was something like `import window` at the top but without it feels uncomfortable knowing I might accidentally use one of these variables at any point.

Comment: @Jazcash "window" is actually a property of the global object which points to itself (see [`window.window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.window)), and all properties of the global object are part of the global scope. JavaScript has lexical scoping so inner scopes can reference identifiers from outer scopes (hence how the `window` identifier resolves to the global object). You can put your code inside an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) and all variable/function definitions won't conflict with the global ones. `=]`

Comment: My personal setup is `(function(){ 'use strict;' /*code here*/ }());`, this way var/function declarations do not conflict with the global scope and undeclared variables do not leak to the global scope (throws a ReferenceError instead, see [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode)). Hopefully ES6 Modules will be standardized soon enough to get us rid of this boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using prototype at all, it's better to put functions on the constructors prototype. For more info about constructor functions and prototype you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

As for why age is not logged; it's because you're trying to log window.age instead of p.age

```
p = new Person("Bob", 12);
console.log(p.name);
console.log(p.age);
console.log("this is:",this);
console.log("does window have a name property?",typeof this.name);
console.log("does window have an age property?",typeof this.age);
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm just learning this stuff now. The code in the question was just one of my test examples. Thank you though.